# Problem with Mayavi import error in matlab

Tags: python-3.7, vtk, mayavi

I have created this environment:

```
conda create -n mbn_env -c conda-forge python=3.7 seaborn matplotlib pandas click basemap scikit-image nb_conda nibabel vtk netcdf4 mayavi
```

and I'm using the code from this link: https://github.com/guischu09/MultipleSampling-MBN

However, when I run the code, this appears:

```
Computing MBNs: 100%  [..........] Done.
Computing global graph measures ... 
Computing local graph measures: 100%  [..........] Done.
Done! Check graph measures at: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\MultipleSampling-MBN-main\output
Plotting networks ... 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\MultipleSampling-MBN-main\lib\plotscript_mayavi.py", line 23, in <module> 
    from mayavi.mlab import * 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 16, in <module> 
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 24, in <module> 
    from .engine_manager import get_engine 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 14, in <module> 
    from mayavi.core.registry import registry 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\registry.py", line 16, in <module> 
    from mayavi.core.metadata import Metadata, import_symbol 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\metadata.py", line 11, in <module> 
    from mayavi.core.pipeline_info import PipelineInfo 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\pipeline_info.py", line 12, in <module> 
    from .utils import get_tvtk_dataset_name 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\utils.py", line 2, in <module> 
    import vtk 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\vtk.py", line 31, in <module> 
    all_m = importlib.import_module('vtkmodules.all') 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module 
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\all.py", line 37, in <module> 
    from .vtkIOVeraOut import * 
ImportError: DLL load failed: NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o procedimento especificado. 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\MultipleSampling-MBN-main\lib\plotscript_mayavi.py", line 23, in <module> 
    from mayavi.mlab import * 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 16, in <module> 
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 24, in <module> 
    from .engine_manager import get_engine 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 14, in <module> 
    from mayavi.core.registry import registry 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\registry.py", line 16, in <module> 
    from mayavi.core.metadata import Metadata, import_symbol 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\metadata.py", line 11, in <module> 
    from mayavi.core.pipeline_info import PipelineInfo 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\pipeline_info.py", line 12, in <module> 
    from .utils import get_tvtk_dataset_name 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\utils.py", line 2, in <module> 
    import vtk 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\vtk.py", line 31, in <module> 
    all_m = importlib.import_module('vtkmodules.all') 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module 
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\mbn_env\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\all.py", line 37, in <module> 
    from .vtkIOVeraOut import * 
ImportError: DLL load failed: NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o procedimento especificado. 
Error using importdata (line 139)
Unable to open file.

Error in circularGraph (line 94)
      pyColors = importdata(this.ColorMap); pyColors = pyColors.data;

Error in PlotNets (line 260)
                    circularGraph(network,'colormap',colormap_file,'Label',strrep(Labels,'_','-'));

Error in main (line 33)
PlotNets(output,setup,Labels,Atlas,Coords,true)
 
>>
```

I have tried reinstalling vtk and mayavi using conda and pip, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I'm very new to python, so I don't know much.